# A best aesthetics to indicate the angle between two vectors

Tags: symbols, mathtools, mtpro, amssymb, newtxmath

For my book I'm using this code with (`mtpro2[lite]` package) to indicate the angle between two vectors,

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}
\usepackage{mathtools,amssymb}   
\begin{document}
\[\widehat{\bar{r}\,\bar{v}}\]
\end{document}
```

that it produces this output:

[image]

I am not able to find an optimal solution to reduce the angular opening of the `\widehat` command whose angle vertex does not go too high and which, if possible, the edges of the angle end along the midpoint of the `\bar` command.

A very rough example could be this:

[image]

Any suggestions for improvement are appreciated.

Comment: `\sphericalangle`?

Comment: @marmot I don't like. Thank you for comment.

Comment: Is the notation used somewhere else?

Comment: When I was in high-school (prehistoric times…), the oriented angle of two vectors was simply denoted $(\vec r, \vec v)$

Comment: @egreg In my book that I'm working on, I used it very little if you mean this. If I mean that I have seen it somewhere else in some textbook my answer is no. I don't just like it aesthetically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Revised based on OP desire for lower hat.  Here I lower it 1pt from where `\widehat` would normally place it.  Also, does not presently work in smaller math styles, but that is easy to fix.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}
\usepackage{mathtools,amssymb} 
\newcommand\myangle[2]{
  \setbox0=\hbox{$\!\bar{#1}\,\bar{#2}\!$}
  \ht0=\dimexpr\ht0-1pt\relax
  \,\widehat{\copy0}\,}  
\begin{document}
\[=\myangle{r}{v}=\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hopefully the translator will help me: a little lower down `\widehat` you could have to see the difference? Thank you very much also to you.

Comment: @Sebastiano Please see my edit.  Let me know if you need it in smaller math styles.

Comment: It's perfect for me!!! Even in a year I couldn't create your code. :-)...studying all the possible manuals.

Comment: I like it very much; in my book I moved it up a little bit `\ht0-0.5pt` because into my code it was almost near the vector bar with my fonts.